# Creating animation point using openlayers and geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Before getting started on creating points that are animated like this using flash
http://adventure.nationalgeographic.com/adventure/trips/americas-best-adventures/map/
I would like to know if it is possible in anyway to create animated point using openlayers and geoserver. If it is what are the different ways? I saw [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/rotate-features.html) example.

Answer (score 4):

The Openlayers documentation refers to a tween function that will fire off a function every so often http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Tween-js.html.

Perhaps having it fire on the mouse over function and animate a circle growing around your point? I don't see why it wouldn't be possible...